# Run operation on multiple OGG files in a directory

Tags: windows, batch-file, for-loop, sox

Im trying to make a routine in Windows batch that will run "sox.exe" on every OGG file in a specified directory.  I currently have the problem that its not handling paths correctly, let alone, perform the operation correctly.  If I run the command, by hand, in a terminal window, for each file individually, it works fine.

I also want to make the output file a different name (otherwise the resulting file gets goobered up big time.

"sox.exe FAIL formats: can't open output file `\temp\OGG\Rain.ogg': No such file or directory"

```
@echo off

setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
cd Data
mkdir temp

for %%A in ("OGG\*.ogg") do (
sox.exe %%A -C 0 \temp\%%A
)
```

General layout of files is as follows:

```
OptOGG
  |--OptOGG.bat
  |
  |--Data
     |--OGG
     |  |--AudioFile.ogg
     |
     |--sox.exe
```

I have all the sox.exe dependencies there, too, and its been tested by hand to work, I just didnt include them in the layout above.

Basically, I want to perform the sox operation on all ogg files in a directory (will be changed later to a remote device directory), have them end up in a temporary directory, then move them back to their original directory, overwriting the original files, keeping the same name as the original.

Answer (score 0):

A relative path starting with `.\` references the current directory.

A relative path starting with `..\` references the parent directory of current directory.

A relative path starting with just `\` references the root of current drive.

So you created the temp folder in data folder, but specified in **FOR** loop the temp folder in root of current drive where no `Temp` folder existed.

This batch code with additional checks should do what you want.

```
@echo off
setlocal

rem Get drive and path of batch file ending with a backslash and append
rem Data which is the name of the data folder containing in subfolder
rem OGG the audio files to optimize.
set "DataFolder=%~dp0Data"

rem Does this folder exist?
if not exist "%DataFolder%" (
    echo Folder %DataFolder% does not exist!
    goto EndBatch
)

if not exist "%DataFolder%\OGG" (
    echo Folder %DataFolder%\OGG does not exist!
    goto EndBatch
)

if not exist "%DataFolder%\OGG\*.ogg" (
    echo Folder %DataFolder%\OGG does not contain any OGG file.
    goto EndBatch
)

set "TempFolder=%DataFolder%\Temp"
if not exist "%TempFolder%" (
    mkdir "%TempFolder%"
    if errorlevel 1 (
        echo Failed to create %TempFolder%
        goto EndBatch
    )
)

rem Run SOX on every OGG file in subfolder OGG of data
rem folder with output file written to temp folder.
for %%A in ("%DataFolder%\OGG\*.ogg") do (
    echo "%DataFolder%\sox.exe" "%%~fA" -C 0 "%TempFolder%\%%~nxA"
)
endlocal
goto :EOF

:EndBatch
endlocal
echo.
echo Press any key to exit batch job %~n0.
pause >nul
```

For understanding the used commands and how they work, open a command prompt window, execute there the following commands, and read entirely all help pages displayed for each command very carefully.

- `echo /?`
- `endlocal /?`
- `for /?`
- `goto /?`
- `if /?`
- `mkdir /?`
- `pause /?`
- `rem /?`
- `set /?`
- `setlocal /?`

Comment: Thanks.  Very helpful.  I finally came up with a script that works like I want (close).  Its not perfect, as it doesnt pull files with spaces in the filename.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks.  Very helpful.  I finally came up with a script that works like I want (close).  Its not perfect, as it doesnt pull files with spaces in the filename.  This is part of a much larger script, so optimizations label is elsewhere.

```
if %choice% == a (
  if exist OGG del /Q OGG
  @md OGG
  cls
  Echo.
  Echo  Mounting system R/W...
  adb remount
  Echo.
  Echo  Pulling audio files...
  adb pull /system/media/audio/alarms/ .
  for %%a in ("*.ogg") do (
    Echo %%a
    sox.exe %%a -C 0 "%current%\Data\OGG\%%a"
  )
  Echo.
  Echo  Pushing optimized audio back to device...
  adb push OGG /system/media/audio/alarms
  @rmdir /S /Q OGG
  @del *.ogg
  Echo.
  Echo  Optimizations complete!
  Pause
  goto optimizations
)
```

Comment: Use `sox.exe "%%a" -C 0 "%current%\Data\OGG\%%a"` with quotes around first `%%a` and your batch file works also for OGG files containing 1 or more spaces in file name. And string comparisons should be done also with using quotes, i.e. first line should be `if "%choice%" == "a" (` in your code.